# Find an integer function $f(n)$ that is even for $n\not \equiv 2\bmod 3$, and odd for $n\equiv 2\bmod 3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Does a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ that satisfies
$$
f(n) \equiv \begin{cases}0 \bmod{2}, & n\equiv 0,1\bmod{3} \\ 1\bmod{2}, & n\equiv 2\bmod{3} \end{cases}
$$
exist (with an explicit formula)? In other words, is there an elementary expression that satisfies the above?

Comment: Did you mean to ask if it exists, or do you want to know if it has a conventional name. These are two different things.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I want to know if there is any explicit formula.

Comment: There's not much to show for existence. You almoast wrote down such a function already. So, that gives you existence

Comment: The residue of $n^2(n+1)^2$ mod 3?

Comment: Well, I am trying to find like a polynomial expression, or using the floor function. For example, $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 1$ satisfies that it is even for $n = 4k+1,4k+2$ and odd for $n = 4k,4k+3$, for $k\geq 1$.

Comment: @almagest this expression is always $0\mod{2}$, since it contains a product of successor integers.

Comment: @Joshhh But it is not always 0 mod 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*explaining the solution through floors*
You are looking for the function $f(n)$ of period $3$, which is $1$ for $n =  \cdots , - 1,2,5, \cdots $ and null elsewhere 
(i.e., $f(n) = \left[ {\bmod (n,3) = 2} \right]$ where brackets denote Iverson bracket or the already mentioned $1_{\,A} $function).
Then its sum is clearly $F(n) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,\,n} {f(k)}  = \left\lfloor {{{n + 1} \over 3}} \right\rfloor  = 1 + \left\lfloor {{{n - 2} \over 3}} \right\rfloor $
and $f(n) = F(n) - F(n - 1) = \left\lfloor {{{n - 2} \over 3}} \right\rfloor  - \left\lfloor {{{n - 3} \over 3}} \right\rfloor  = \left\lfloor {{{n + 1} \over 3}} \right\rfloor  - \left\lfloor {{n \over 3}} \right\rfloor  =  \cdots $

*a solution with cosine*
You can also interpolate the "train of pulses" represented by $f(n)$ by
$f(x) = {1 \over 3} + {2 \over 3}\cos \left( {{2 \over 3}\pi \left( {x + 1} \right)} \right)$, or by its whole Fourier series if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are looking for, but the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function#Definition) will meet your requirements. Just take $A=3\mathbb N+2=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid n\equiv 2\bmod 3\}$. Then the function $\mathbf {1}_A:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ defined by $$\mathbf 1_A=\begin{cases}0,& n\not\equiv 2\bmod 3\\
1,& n\equiv 2\bmod 3\end{cases}$$ does the trick already.